# Updating dropdown list with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, controller

I want to have the opportunity to select from a dropdown list a value and to click on a link to get the next Value of the dropdown list. How could I update the selected Value from the dropdown list if I click on the link?

```
<select class="dropdown-select" name="mySelect" id="chapter" ng-options="option.Icnumber for option in selected" 
ng-model="selected.Icnumber" ng-change="updateChapter(selected.Icnumber.Icnumber)">
</select>

<a ng-show="nextChapter" class="ng-hide" ng-click="updateChapterNext(selected.Icnumber.Icnumber)">Next Chapter</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular has a feature called two ways binding, what ever you have in $scope and use it in the template, when you update the value in the controller, it will automatically update the value in the template.

for your problem you use `selected` as the dropdown value.

so in your `updateChapterNext` function modify the value for `selected`

so

```
$scope.updateChapterNext = function(param){
  // do your thing to call next chapter
  // and assign the response or new value to selected
  $scope.selected = newValueForSelected;
}
```

this will update the selected value on the dropdown